# Where is the missing Symfony Gallery

Tags: image, symfony, gallery

OK, so for a couple of weeks I've been getting to grips with Symfony. Coming from working with Drupal a lot and wanting more control I've really grasped a lot of Symfony concepts– great! However in trying to replicate and entity field type which allows multiple images to be attached to and removed from an entity I'm really banging my head against a brick wall with this.

We are talking about a Product with a Gallery or numerous other scenarios where many images would relate to one thing.

I've followed the Symfony Cookbook article on embedding forms and failed to get a usable instance of One product allowing upload of Many images.

I'm just a bit surprised that there isn't a bundle or even some better documentation out there to handle what I would of thought to be highly demanded functionality.

I've looked briefly at the CMF but to be honest I like the simplicity of the standalone Symfony system as it has a simplistic appeal for very small CMS sites and systems that don't require the concepts talked about in CMF. If I were after a lot of that functionality then I would sooner revert to Drupal or similar.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

BTW. I'm not interested in creating the product first and then creating multiple images and relating them to the product. I could figure this out if necessary. It needs to be driven via on create/edit form.

Comment: I also comes from Drupal, and never back to that poor, shitty piece of code with ~200 db queries/request to display "hello world".  Keep in mind that symfony is not for clickers, it's for programmers, there is no bundles for every small thing (like drupal module to display cookie compliance - sick). You can create product, image, and embed image form in product, or even any other form you imagine.

Comment: I appreciate your point and I am very much embracing the migration from using a cms where everything is geared around browser based configuration. Having evolved as a Drupal developer I've realised the limitations hence driven to embracing a more ground up approach and symf. Just struggling with this particular aspect and documentation regarding what I guess must have been achieved 1000's of times over. Any pointers for a newbie appreciated? Am I on the right track with a collection field on product to create multiple images that hold the product is as reference or missing something obvious?